# Flash classic tween on graphic replays at end keyframe

Tags: flash, movieclip

I've been trying to export my animation into Premiere where I am compiling a video and to do so, after trying every other possible solution, is to export a PNG sequence from Flash.

In doing so however, nested animations inside MovieClips fail to animate (stuck on first frame) and AS3 is ignored.

I've painfully edited out the code and converted my MovieClips to Graphic symbols, which allow nested animations.

The issue is, that a Classic Tween applied to a graphic tends to call the graphic to run on both start and end keyframes. Unlike a MC which is synced to behavior of keyframes as it relates to the instance of the animation and not a copy of it.

Is there any way to prevent this? So have it render as a graphic and apply a classic tween to the object (play once, no loop) and have it really play only once?

Using Flash CS6, but applies to all versions.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution thus far, is to specify on each keyframe, both start and end, different looping properties.

It's not a perfect solution but it works well.

For instance, on the start keyframe, i specify `Play Once` and on the end keyframe i set it manually to a `Single Frame` which is most appropriate to display.